# How to support input type="number" tag in IE browser

Tags: html, css

I've been using `input type="number"`, it shows in Chrome normally, but not the IE browser. In IE, it shows a 'X' marked button. I want to show it as top and bottom arrows marked button.

My IE browser's version is 11, also I tried `meta` tag enable browser to make rendered recent browser, but I couldn't solve this.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

[image]

[image]

What's the matter?
How Can I fix this? please help me.

This is what I've so far :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
  <title>jQuery UI Spinner - Default functionality</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  input[type=number] {
    height: 30px;
}

input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button {  
    width: 14px;
    height: 30px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" name="qty" value="1" name="goodsnum">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Per caniuse.com, `input type="number"` is supported in IE 10 and 11, but without the increment/decrement buttons. https://caniuse.com/#search=number

Comment: As @Kai said the arrow you are looking for is not supported on IE11, but to help you, look at Polyfills  - https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: thanks Kai,@KaoriYui, I'll refer to yours, and find any solutions or replacements.